# "The operand can't be null", even though the documentation of the employed method clearly specifies a possible null-return?

Tags: dart, io, null, dart-null-safety

I'm using an IO Library which returns a `Future<String>`. While, yes, the returned type is `String` instead of `String?`, the documentation of that library method clearly states that `null` will be returned if the operation fails (Instead of throwing an exception). Therefore, I need to check for null myself and handle the exception throwing myself.

However, if I check the return value for null, Dart tells me that the operand can't be null and I therefore shouldn't be checking for it.

What should be done in such a case?

Comment: What IO lib are we talking about? The null-safety in Dart is what we call "sound" so we will never have a situation where something is typed to return `String` would end up returning `String?` since the runtime would crash the application before ever reaching your code.

Comment: If the library returns a `Future<String>`, it *cannot* return `null`.  The documentation most likely is outdated, and you should file an issue against the library to correct it.

Comment: @julemand101 It's called FlutterSecureStorage. The description of their read method says it can return null, but the signature is a Future<String>.

Comment: @Fly Do you mean? https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_secure_storage/latest/flutter_secure_storage/FlutterSecureStorage/read.html Which is documented to have the retun type of `Future<String?>`.

Comment: @julemand101 That's indeed the method, yet in my dev environment it looks like this... `/// Decrypts and returns the value for the given [key] or null if [key] is not in the storage.
  ///
  /// [key] shoudn't be null.
  /// [iOptions] optional iOS options
  /// [aOptions] optional Android options
  /// Can throw a [PlatformException].
  Future<String> read(
      {@required String key,
      IOSOptions iOptions,
      AndroidOptions aOptions})`, so the doc is the same but the signature isn't... Perhaps it has to do with the version? Mine is set to `^3.3.3`

Comment: @Fly What version of the package do you have? It could be that you are using an older version before null-safety was introduced in version 4.0.0 of flutter_secure_storage.

Comment: @Fly Did only now see your version number. Yes, that is definitely an older version which does not support null-safety and which is why the returned type is just `Future<String>` since it does not support the concept of `String?`. If the rest of your project supports null-safety, you should update this dependency to its latest version.

Answer (score 1):

As is discussed in the comments, this issue can be seen when using legacy code that hasn't been updated for Dart 2.12 with null-safety.

In previous versions of Dart (pre-2.12), types did not have to have a trailing `?` symbol to signify that a value may be `null`. A `Future<String>`, for example, could easily complete with a value of `null`.

To avoid this, make sure all your dependencies are null-safe.